# Changing Buttons from Relative Layout to Linear Layout weird side-effects

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, layout

The strangest thing happened to me today and caused hours of frustration and anger-management issues.

I had a working Android slideshow application. However, I was unhappy with the buttons (which were in a Relative Layout), and moved them to a Linear Layout. However, when running my application, the behavior of the buttons got swapped around (ie Button 1 did Button 2's work and vice-versa). I was able to remedy this by changing the id of ONE of the buttons, not all (that didn't work). Also related to this, was that my application started crashing when I switched orientation. It had worked previously when I had the Relative Layout. (I am using a Handler to change the UI for the slideshow)

I was unable to solve this issue, so I reverted to my Relative Layout, but I would like to know how this could have happened in the first place.

The layout that works:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageView"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/startStop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/startStop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/startStop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_next" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/startStop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/previous"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_media_previous" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code that causes problems:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/image1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#30eee9e9" >

            <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/previous"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_previous" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/startStop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_next" />
```

Comment: can you post your layout xml and code where you handled button click ?

Comment: you must have used LeftOff or RightOff functionality of the Relative Layout(as PARENT), is it so?

Comment: I'm guessing that you app crashes after an orientation change because of a ClassCast or NullPointer Exception. Do you have a different layout for portrait and landscape? If so you need to update both layouts. But without relevant **code** and **logcat** errors we can only guess.

Comment: In order to see why it was crashing you need to look at the logcat. Goto Windows-->Show View -->Logcat and look for red exception area. If you click on the line with your package name it will show the error poing. Also might want to post error log.

Comment: Btw, the reason that there is a +4 on comment above is because 4 readers myself included think you should post more information.

Comment: So please post both the layout information and also crash log so we can help.  Any time spent debugging is not wasted.  This is really important to be able to locate errors since is always another one.

Comment: Whenever there's a button functionality swap like that, it's usually caused by an out-of-date R file that resulted because you fiddled with the xml file.  For whatever reason, the R file didn't get regenerated with the new references so you say "assign this action to button 1" but the code reads "assign this action to button 2".  Rebuild your project by doing `Project->Clean` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: It turns out that the error was that I had two layouts, and only my portrait layout had buttons within the linear layout while the landscape version had the buttons in their original layout

Comment: @DeeV, I get what you mean, but when I modified the layout, the changes were purely cosmetic. I didn't change any properties of the buttons or code referencing the buttons which is why I found it so strange. It turns out that Android was getting confused when I changed orientation since the buttons there were no longer in a linear layout there. The only reason I put the buttons in a linear layout was to create a transparent overlay

Comment: @user929404: I know.  This happens to me all the time when I swap widgets around.  What I suggested most likely wouldn't have solved the crashing problem (which you seem to have figured out), but you said that button2 was doing the functionality of button1.  Cleaning the projects solves this problem for me 90% of the time.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem but with Relative Layout as parent & Linear Layout as child layout I took four imagebuttons

- PLAY
- SCORE
- HELP
- QUIT

And buttons functionality was shifted to one below next i.e. when I pressed PLAY nothing happened when pressed SCORE Game started playing when clicked HELP showed me score and so on.. I put my whole night for solving the problem but nothing happened I shutted off dam thing tried to watch movie but for a while  I was getting boared watching it I started Eclipse again  and the magic that it was working so fine. Dont know But Rebuild & Clean has solved my problem as DeeV said

Comment: This isn't really an answer but a confirmation that Deev's comment helped for you.  If you found Deev's comment helpful, you would want to simply upvote it!